# VSCode How do I skip past an automatically generated end </tag>?

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, tags

Say I were typing

```
<h2>Show Subject*</h2>
```

How would I jump to the end of the brackets if my cursor was at the *. Usually I would just arrow key right 4 times or use my mouse to select the next line. I see others on youtube doing this easily.

example: https://youtu.be/PlxWf493en4?t=567

Her cursor instantly jumps to the end of the . My < > also do not highlight as hers does when I autogenerate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magics you're seeing in the linked video are features of [Emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet). For example there's `Emmet: Go to matching pair`, which you can bind to something convenient using the Keyboard Shortcuts dialog (`Ctrl-k Ctrl-s`). Try `Ctrl-Shift-p` to bring up the command pallete and then type `Emmet` to see all of the available commands. I would suggest taking some time to read the docs and discover what functionality is available to you.

What looks like jumping to the outside of the end tag in the video is really just jumping to the end of the line, which is bound by default to the `End` key. Also useful is word jumping (`Ctrl+RightArrow`/`Ctrl+LeftArrow`) and word selection (`Ctrl+Shift+RightArrow`/`Ctrl+Shift+LeftArrow`). You might take a look at [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#Text_editing) for a fairly comprehensive list of common shortcuts.